# Does LSF io index report NFS io?

Tags: nas, nfs, io, cluster

We use SONAS for our filesystem on our cluster and I have noticed that the load on SONAS does not necessarily correlate with the value of `io` on the cluster nodes when I run `lsload -l`. Is it possible that the `io` value is just printing out values of local (scratch, etc.) storage for each node and has nothing to do with how hard the node is hitting SONAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSF doesn't report NFS io in the io index.

From [the documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_admin/load_indices.dita?lang=en).

> I/O rate (io)
>
> The io index measures I/O throughput to disks attached directly to
>   this host, in KB per second. It does not include I/O to disks that are
>   mounted from other hosts.

If you want the NFS io rate to be available (e.g., for use in a resource requirement string), you can [write an elim](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_admin/chap_elim_lsf_admin.dita?lang=en) to collect it.  I'm not sure what the best way is to measure it. A couple of ideas: `/proc/net/rpc/nfs` or something that SONAS provides.  If using `/proc/net/rpc/nfs`, an instantaneous measurement may not be that useful. Might need to report an average over a history of samples.